# Powershell, extract-archive and subdirectories

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Is there a way I can use Powershell's extract-archive to extract a subfolder of a zip?

For example, I have a zip called `a.zip`. Inside that zip is a folder called `a`, and inside that folder is a folder called `b` with a bunch of files in it. I want to extract the folder `b` to, for example, `C:\SomeFolder` such that the final structure is `C:\SomeFolder\b` and not `C:\SomeFolder\a\b`

Comment: Sure, extract all, move 'b' to where you want it, delete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible with `Expand-Archive`. I recommend using 7zip if possible.
Here's how to do it without using external commands such as 7zip.

```
using namespace System.IO.Compression
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$zipPath = "C:\a.zip"
$destDirPath = "C:\SomeFolder"
$targetEntry = "a/b/"

$zip = [ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipPath)
$zip.Entries.Where{ $_.FullName -match "$targetEntry.*[^/]$" }.ForEach{
    $newFile = [IO.FileInfo]($destDirPath,$_.FullName -join "/")
    $newFile.Directory.Create()
    [ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, $newFile)
}
$zip.Dispose()
```